# Cannot build SonarSource/sonarqube

Tags: sonarqube

After cloning the [github repository](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube), updating Maven to 3.0.5, updating the JDK, and executing the build.sh, my build of sonarqube failed after a number of unit test failures, the first of which reads

```
app_with_severities_when_period_is_set(org.sonar.server.component.ws.ComponentAppActionTest)      Time elapsed: 0.007 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: periods[0][2]
Expected: 2014-05-08T00:00:00+0200
     got: 2014-05-08T00:00:00-0500

at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:222)
at org.skyscreamer.jsonassert.JSONAssert.assertEquals(JSONAssert.java:192)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WsTester$Result.assertJson(WsTester.java:193)
at org.sonar.server.ws.WsTester$Result.assertJson(WsTester.java:183)
at org.sonar.server.component.ws.ComponentAppActionTest.app_with_severities_when_period_is_set(ComponentAppActionTest.java:400)
```

The build message was

```
[INFO] SonarQube :: Search ............................... SUCCESS [55.995s]
[INFO] SonarQube :: Server ............................... FAILURE [5:23.832s]
[INFO] SonarQube :: Plugins :: Xoo ....................... SKIPPED
```

I have obtained this problem on MacOSX, Ubuntu, EL5 and EL6. Is there any way around it?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue on test execution with other timezone than Europe/Paris.
You can try building SQ with `-Duser.timezone="Europe/Paris"`

Comment: Where should I put that option? I tried putting it in the ``build.sh``, but ``mvn -Duser.timezone="Europe/Paris" clean install $*`` doesn't work.